# Deploy failure on Heroku - Ruby (on windows)

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, heroku

I downloaded and installed Ruby, Ruby gems and with it installed Jekyll. Started a test project with Jekyll. Want to deploy it on Heroku (because gh-pages don't support plugins on Jekyll).

Read docs on Heroku for ruby, downloaded and installed JDK 8 and JRuby 9.1.17.0. Installed bundler.

Logged in Heroku, and executed following commands in terminal:

```
heroku create
git push heroku master
heroku open
```

The new heroku app build succeeded but the website fails to load. It displays error like so:

[This is the error displayed when I check heroku logs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xtHnq.png)

I also built a Procfile in the root folder for the test project. Entered the following code:

```
web: puma -t 5:5 -p ${PORT:-3000} -e ${RACK_ENV:-development}
```

I'm not sure what went wrong. Please help!

Comment: puma is not found, do you have it in your Gemfile? and make sure it is not under the development group if you want to use it in production.

Comment: @Eyeslandic No, Puma is not in my gem file! is it a gem? I thought it was a bash command. So, can I use `bundle add puma` ? This is probably too much to ask, but could you please elaborate on the 2nd part of your comment?

Comment: Just add puma as you add any other gem to your Gemfile, `gem 'puma'` and then `bundle install`. I have not used Heroku however so I have no idea whether this will solve your issue.

Comment: Heroku's Puma docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/deploying-rails-applications-with-the-puma-web-server

Answer (score -1):

You need to figure out what's your web-server by default. As advised by **Roberto**, it might be puma.

By the default, when you run `rails new`, it always has the web-server gem (puma, passenger, unicorn or anything else).

It seems that you've copied some settings? And that's why you don't have puma in Gemfile, but trying to run it. You might share the Gemfile list to let you know what's wrong.